# Typehead in ng2-bootstrap cannot show items in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

> UPDATED: It supports now nested property now. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/135

---

I am using [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/) in Angular 2.

I am trying to use Typeahead.

The example code

```
private statesComplex:Array<any> = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Alabama'}, {id: 2, name: 'Alaska'}, {id: 3, name: 'Arizona'}];
```

and

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selected"
       [typeahead]="statesComplex"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
       [typeaheadOptionField]="'name'"
       class="form-control">
```

runs well.

But when I try to change the data format

```
private statesComplex:Array<any> = [
    {id: 1, profile: {name: 'Alabama', email: '111'}}, {id: 2, profile: {name: 'Alaska', email: '222'}}, {id: 3, profile: {name: 'Arizona', email: '333'}}];
```

and use

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selected"
       [typeahead]="statesComplex"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
       [typeaheadOptionField]="'profile.name'"
       class="form-control">
```

It does not work. I think the problem is related with typeaheadOptionField, but I don't know how to write it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this kind of notation is not going to be recognised as nested property of sub-object (see [source](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/0dec605ad09323a051d1a9807ef465ce04e4e46e/components/typeahead/typeahead.directive.ts#L115)). In this case, you could preprocess data a little bit. Maybe by actually introducing this helper property:

```
this.statesComplex.forEach(state => state['profile.name'] = state.profile.name);
```

It will add new `profile.name` property to all objects so typeahead should work as expected.

Comment: Wow, this is so amazing, you read the source code! It works now! I will suggest the author support nested property if possible. Thank you so much!